# How to delete all music on my iPhone

Tags: iphone, itunes, music, music.app

How do I delete all the music on my iPhone.  I tried doing it through iTunes but it says my collection is not managed by iTunes and I don't want to erase and sync because all my apps are nicely backed up and sorted with iTunes.

I have only seen a way of deleting song by song on the phone.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Make sure you really want to delete all the music because they can’t be restored afterwards.

1. Open **General » Usage** in **Settings**.
2. Wait for iOS to load all the apps that take up the storage of your iPhone/iPad.
3. Find and select **Music** from the list.
4. You’ll see **All Music** in the list. Tap the `Edit` button on the top right, and choose to delete **All Music**.

Comment: This leaves all the songs on the Music App greyed out. If I tap on any of them, It says "Item not available - This Item cannot be played"